# Can I access Office 365 Business Essentials email in Outlook Desktop if I purchased the desktop apps separately?

Tags: outlook, office365

We have a contractor who we've purchased an Office 365 Business Essentials license for to set her up with email on our domain. We are aware that does not come with the Outlook Desktop application.

She is wondering how she can, at her own expense, purchase a 365 subscription for herself to use Outlook Desktop for her Business Essentials email. We asked her to purchase Office 365 Personal using their personal email address, which includes the desktop app, because we assumed we could then add her Business Essentials account in there as well. It doesn't work. It fails when trying to add her account to Outlook Desktop.

Is this a licensing issue that prevents this, or are we just possibly missing something technical? If it's a licensing restriction, is there *any* way she could get it to work? (E.g. what if she purchased her own Business Premium separately instead and then tried to add her Essentials email?)

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is customer service-related and not a programming related question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this doesn't belong here. I reached out to Microsoft Support and they confirmed, yes, the 365 Personal license with desktop apps will cover a Business Essentials email address being added to Outlook Desktop.

That answers this question. My issue I'll have to resolve with them is something else technical in nature.